# R: how to re-order vector elements by name

Tags: r, vector

```
s <- c("West", "North", "South", "East")
```

I have a vector with 4 elements. I'd like to reorder them so the vector contains `"North", "South", "West", "East"`. I know one way of re-ordering them via indices as follows.

```
s[c(2, 3, 1, 4)]
```

But is there a way to re-order them by name? Something along the lines of `s["North", "South", "West," "East"]` (which does not work). Note that each element in the vector is unique.

Comment: That's not a named vector, but it were, say `s <- c(West = 1, North = 2, South = 3, East = 4)`, you can pass a vector of names just like a vector of indices: `s[c("North", "South", "West", "East")]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I'm not sure if it will fit your purpose but one option is to convert your vector to `ordered` factor and then `sort` it.

```
s <- c("West", "North", "South", "East")


s <- ordered(s, c("North", "South", "West", "East"))  #Define the order in which you want it

s <- sort(s)  #Now sort vector. This could have been done as part of previous step itself

s
# [1] North South West  East 
# Levels: North < South < West < East
```

Comment: This is probably the simplest way. The best I could do otherwise was `s[order(match(s,c("North","South","East","West")))]`